# Leaflet popup can't change position

Tags: javascript, leaflet, popup

I want to update my [leaflet popup](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#popup) position. The reason is, when I click on a generalized polyline (because of lower zoom level) and then zoom to the clicked position, my click position is not exactly on the object and therefore also my popup position is not exactly on the object.

```
function zoomToFeature(e) {
        console.log("ZOOM TO FEATURE");
        // Set new selection
        selected = e.target;
        clickposition = e.latlng;
        console.log("Selected layer:");
        console.log(selected);
        console.log("My clickposition: " + clickposition);
        let closest_latlng = L.GeometryUtil.closest(mymap, selected.getLatLngs(), clickposition)
        console.log("New Latlng calculated: " + closest_latlng);
        var popup = selected.getPopup();          
        console.log("SET LATLNG");
        popup.setLatLng(closest_latlng).openOn(mymap).update();
        console.log("Popup: ")
        console.log(popup);
        console.log("Popup getLatLng: ")
        console.log(popup.getLatLng());
    }
```

And that is my output:

[image]

It's really strange, my popup object has the old latlng values from the clickposition. But when I print the method "getLatLng()" then the new caclulated values are shown. The problem is, on the map the popup is also shown on the clickposition and not on my new calculated position. My question is, how can I correctly update the position of my popup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it was completly something different then I actualy thought... so I post it here, maybe it helps someone else too.

The problem was my click event `zoomToFeature(e)` was the first event in the event order. And after this event was the default leaflet `_openPopup(t)` event. This default `_openPopup(t)` event then reseted my position of the popup.

Now I looked on the part where I create the popup content . Because the content is created from an ajax call, I now wait until the content is completly loaded and bound to my layer with `layer.bindPopup(popup);` After that I added my custom on click event `zoomToFeature(e)`.

My event order on the layer is now like this:

[image]